# Webmatrix3: Inserting PHP code bugs out JavaScript color syntax

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-highlighting, webmatrix

I'm using Webmatrix3 for PHP developing.
I found this issue: 
when I insert PHP code, like reading a PHP variable into my javascipt code, Webmatrix ide lost syntax hilighting, and all the code appears black.
The code syntax is still correct, but it's very difficult to code without color syntax help.

[image: This is a screenshot of what's appens]

Any suggestion or trick to resolve this?